# Default regional settings changed during upgrade to .NET core 1.0

Tags: c#, .net-core

In .NET core RC1 the following piece of code

```
11.12.ToString("0.##")
```

returned '11.12' whereas in RTM 1.0 it returns '11,12'.

As far as I know we did not change anything else. I assume it has to do with some kind of default regional settings but I'm not sure.

Is there an explanation for this?

Comment: This is the expected output for cultures that use `,` as decimal separator. What does `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` return for you? Are you sure the culture settings on your machine didn't change? Why is the explanation important for you?

Comment: I also suspect that your 1.0 installation is a localized variation. During development (Beta/RC) there is not so much benefit of shipping these.

Comment: Thx for the comments. I finally added specific culture using CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-GB") and it worked. I am still slightly confused by this changed during an upgrade to .NET Core 1.0.